# How to simplify a case_when() inside a mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and I want to add a column. For that purpose, I use dplyr::mutate. However, the values of the column I want to add depend of the value of other column. I use case_when() and the problem is solved, but if there are many cases the code is uncomfortable to write (I show an example below), so I want to know if there is another option (maybe a loop) to simplify this.

The following code works:

```
NewTable <- Table %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ColumnB = case_when(
               ColumnA=="2000" ~ 0,
               ColumnA=="2001" ~ 4,
               ColumnA=="2002" ~ 8,
               ColumnA=="2003" ~ 12,
               ColumnA=="2004" ~ 16,
               ColumnA=="2005" ~ 20,
               ColumnA=="2006" ~ 24,
               ColumnA=="2007" ~ 28,
               ColumnA=="2008" ~ 32,
               ColumnA=="2009" ~ 36,
               ColumnA=="2010" ~ 40,
               ColumnA=="2011" ~ 44))
```

How can I improve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe a lookup table, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35636315/680068) , possible duplicate.

Comment: Since there is no easy, straight forward function/logic that would map a to 0, b to 4, ..., l to 345, you will have to specify their mapping somewhere. Of course you could write a lokk-up tabel, wrap the mapping in a function, etc but this would not reduce the code overall. or I am missing something about your desire?

Comment: @wusel Suppose the mapping is easier: a to 0, b to 2, c to 4, d to 6,... Can I simplify it? My problem is that I need to add more assignments and that supposes to add many rows to my code.

Comment: Provide realistic data, if there is no logic to your groupings then there is only a manual way of recoding columns.

Comment: I have edited the question. That is the particular problem I want to solve. As I need to add more years, I wanted to simplify the code. I'm sorry if it was confusing, I just wanted to propose a general question

Comment: This will map 2000 to 0, 2001 to 4, etc. `4 * (as.numeric(as.character(ColumnA)) -  2000)` .  If `ColumnA` were already character as opposed to factor the `as.character` could be omitted.  Please post reproducible inputs with your posts. See instructions at top of [tag:r].

Comment: If you don't mind telling us: Why this kind of recoding, why not keep as years?

Comment: are you counting trimesters ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have changed your data, you may want to try this:

```
Table<-data.frame(A = c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004"))
Table$B = (as.numeric(as.character(Table$A))-2000)*4
```

If you do not have such a pattern, you could generate a list of values with matching A and B, and merge them:

```
match_list<-data.frame(A = c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004"),
                       B = c(0, 4, 8, 16, 20))
merge(Table, match_list, by = "A")  # Table itself does not have B at this stage
```

This can only save some typing.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a solution using `mapvalues` from `plyr` package. I use it often.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
# Create a simulated data frame

set.seed(9049)

Table <- data.frame(columnA = as.character(sample(2000:2011, 
                                                  size = 100, 
                                                  replace = TRUE)),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Extract unique levels from column A
colA_levels <- unique(Table$columnA)

# Create unique levels of column B to map to
colB_levels <- (as.numeric(colA_levels) - 2000) * 4

# Use `mapvalues` from `plyr` package
# 
NewTable <- Table %>% 
  mutate(columnB = plyr::mapvalues(columnA,
                                   from = colA_levels,
                                   to = colB_levels))

head(NewTable, 10)
#>    columnA columnB
#> 1     2008      32
#> 2     2011      44
#> 3     2007      28
#> 4     2011      44
#> 5     2001       4
#> 6     2010      40
#> 7     2000       0
#> 8     2007      28
#> 9     2000       0
#> 10    2002       8
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it :

```r
lkp <- setNames(c(0, 4, 8, 16, 20),
                c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004"))
df <- data.frame(ColumnA = c("2004","2002"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dplyr::mutate(df, ColumnB = lkp[ColumnA])
#>   ColumnA ColumnB
#> 1    2004      20
#> 2    2002       8
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing the column B, I assume it doesn't exist in Table, so a join could do the trick.

```
library(dplyr)
NewTable <- left_join( Table,
tibble( A = c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004"),
        B = seq(from = 0, to = 32, by = 4) )
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering OPs comment, you could wirte a function then (probs to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37240484/8107362)):

```
library(tidyverse)
letter2num <- function(x) {(utf8ToInt(x) - utf8ToInt("a")) * 2}
tibble(x = letters) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(y = letter2num(x))
```

Comment: This answer is not useful, we need to know the logic for recoding. I doubt they have ABC letters in real data.

Comment: The question has been whether OP culd simplfy it if there is an esay mapping. answer: yes, there is and that is how it could work in the case specified. In a diferent setting, OP would have to adapt the code.